# Triggering a click while preventing other handlers of the same element from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform a click on an element while preventing other handlers on the same element from firing.

```
//Calling this
$(".element").click();
```

However, I want to call stopImmediatePropogation();

```
//I want something like this, doesn't seem to work
$(".element").click(function(e) {
   //stop other handlers from firing
   e.stopImmediatePropagation()
});

$(".element").on("click", function(){
    //this will fire with the previous click.
    //I don't want it to fire.
});
```

but click doesn't seem to take any parameters (that I can see). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `.stopImmediatePropagation` should work, you have something wrong elsewhere, see this https://jsfiddle.net/ucd5d3eu/

Comment: Hmm you are right. That does appear to work.